# Reverse twilight switch

Tags: relay, reverse

I live off-grid and want my fridge switch off automatically during the night.
The strategy combines a twilight switch and a switch relay.

I'm stuck with the wiring of the switch relay (I am not an electrician).

Spec: https://www.phoenixcontact.com/en-pc/products/relay-module-rif-1-rpt-lv-230ac-2x21-2903331

Would you please advise:-

- Which ports are for the power input?
- Which ports are for the control input?
- Can the control input voltage be 230V?
- Which ports are for the reversed output?
- What are the other outputs for?

The inverter has two operation modes:

- continuous
- on-if-need

The on-if-need mode switches on in every minute to check if there's any need.
Ideally I'd use the on-if-need mode to minimize battery usage during the night (there is no timer on the inverter).
I don't know if there's any effect on the relay's designed operation if neither power nor control voltages are applied then it receives either power only or both voltages.

[image]

Many thanks

Comment: I hate initiating a run-around, but if there's not a specific off-grid stackexchange, you'll probably do better on the DIY stackexchange.  Be ready to tell people what voltage you're running (and whether it's AC or DC), whether your installation is subject to local building codes, and if it is, then _where_ it is because building codes are a matter of country and region (e.g. -- in the US they vary from state to state).

Comment: *Why* do you want to turn your fridge off at night? Do you not care if the contents warms up overnight?

Comment: Guys, please compare your "contributions" to Simon B's one and think about it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Which ports are for the power input?

11 and 21

- Which ports are for the control input?

A1 and A2

- Can the control input voltage be 230V?

Yes, it says so on their web site.

- Which ports are for the reversed output?
- What are the other outputs for?

Relays can have two outputs "normally open" and "normally closed".  If no voltage is applied across A1-A2, then 11 is connected to 12 and 21 is connected to 22.  This normally closed or NC.

If power is applied across A1-A2, then 11 is connected to 14 and 21 is connected to 24.  This is the normally open or NO.

It if you want the power to go off when the relay is energised, use the NC outputs.

Answer (score 0):

The link that you provide contains the following schematic:

[image: Switch schematic]

The control input is the ports A1 and A2.

Comment: No, A1 and A2 are for the control input. They're connected to the relay coil.